# unable to load the file into target table using copy into command combined with pattern option

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

when I tried to copy data from snowflake internal named stage, using pattern option  I got this output "Copy executed with 0 files processed"

here is sample code:

copy into <target_table_name> from @test123_stage_int pattern = 'test_.*';

out put of list:

```
 test123_stage_int/test_data.csv.gz
```

file format is :

```
+--------------------------------+---------------+----------------+------------------+
| property                       | property_type | property_value | property_default |
|--------------------------------+---------------+----------------+------------------|
| TYPE                           | String        | CSV            | CSV              |
| RECORD_DELIMITER               | String        | \n             | \n               |
| FIELD_DELIMITER                | String        | |              | ,                |
| FILE_EXTENSION                 | String        |                |                  |
| SKIP_HEADER                    | Integer       | 0              | 0                |
| DATE_FORMAT                    | String        | AUTO           | AUTO             |
| TIME_FORMAT                    | String        | AUTO           | AUTO             |
| TIMESTAMP_FORMAT               | String        | AUTO           | AUTO             |
| BINARY_FORMAT                  | String        | HEX            | HEX              |
| ESCAPE                         | String        | NONE           | NONE             |
| ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD        | String        | \\             | \\               |
| TRIM_SPACE                     | Boolean       | false          | false            |
| FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY   | String        | NONE           | NONE             |
| NULL_IF                        | List          | [\\N]          | [\\N]            |
| COMPRESSION                    | String        | AUTO           | AUTO             |
| ERROR_ON_COLUMN_COUNT_MISMATCH | Boolean       | true           | true             |
| VALIDATE_UTF8                  | Boolean       | true           | true             |
| SKIP_BLANK_LINES               | Boolean       | false          | false            |
| REPLACE_INVALID_CHARACTERS     | Boolean       | false          | false            |
| EMPTY_FIELD_AS_NULL            | Boolean       | true           | true             |
| SKIP_BYTE_ORDER_MARK           | Boolean       | true           | true             |
| ENCODING                       | String        | UTF8           | UTF8
```

Comment: In the pattern there is a period before the asterisk. I assume this is a typo but that's probably what the issue is

Comment: I think the period is accurate, actually.  `.*` is a wildcard per the documentation.

Comment: Is it possible that the file was already loaded?  You'll get the same message if you try to load the same file more than once.

Answer (score 0):

add  parameter FORCE = TRUE  to reload the same file and check if it works.
Also check if your stage file has  data in it.